# tor browser not working

Tags: 13.10

after upgrading ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 my tor-browser stopped taking any input through keyboard. then i deleted tor-browser and when after reinstalling it frm terminal it is showing a message tht your firefox profile couldnot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible .

Comment: can you add the output please `apt-cache policy tor-browser`

Comment: tor-browser:
  Installed: 3.6.1-1~webupd8~0
  Candidate: 3.6.1-1~webupd8~0
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.1-1~webupd8~0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 3):

Ok, try this one:

Open `tor-browser` navigate to `help > trobleshooting information` and click on `reset tor-browser` and restart `tor-browser`

Alternatively, try to completely reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge tor-browser

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

**Important**

If you got a broken profile in your system, to do a complete removal run:

```
sudo rm /home/your_name/.tor-browser-en/INSTALL/Data/Browser/*
```

or you can delete a whole thing like it never was on your system:

```
sudo rm /home/your_name/.tor-browser-en/
```

For Mozilla Firefox:

```
sudo rm /home/your_name/.mozilla/firefox/*
```

You can do this manually by going into your `Home` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and search for the appropriate folders.

Comment: johnny problem is , i m not able to open tor-browser , so i cant do trobleshooting .......... and even after reinstall i am facing same problem... tor-browser is still not launching and  returning msg tht Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.

Comment: you're receiving this problem because of the broken firefox profile in your system, read [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)

Comment: i read it n tryed to make a new profile bt again the same problem... i used the name tor browser for profile name

Comment: did you read and try my updated answer? this should work.

Comment: ur important part.... jst saw rit now .... trying it

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your TOR is in a hidden mode Go to your TOR Browser and right click on properties  and click out of hidden click apply  and close properties